# Watershed segmentation algorithms cannot work correctly in opencv android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv

Watershed segmentation algorithms cannot work in opencv android. I already used Watershed segmentation algorithms in c++ and java. But in android opencv it gives me error. I don't know why? I know Watershed segmentation algorithms takes 2 parameters of Mat typed object one is 8-bit 3 channel image and other one is 32-bit single channel image. But its gives me wrong parameter error.

Comment: What is the full text of the error?

Comment: 07-14 13:37:53.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/segmentation.cpp:147: error: (-210) Only 8-bit, 3-channel input images are supported in function void cvWatershed(const CvArr*, CvArr*)

Comment: Watershed algorithms takes two parameters of typed Mat one is 8-bit 3 channel image and other one is 32-bit single channel image. But in error that I mention above comment both images are 8-bit 3-channel.

Comment: Can you verify the two Mat's you have are of the right type? Use `.depth()` and `.channels()`.

Comment: Yes, I checked. It display channel 4 of first argument. How I resolve this?

Comment: You can post your comment into answer. :)

Comment: i'm really in need of help with this question, can you help me, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216402/how-to-improve-image-segmentation-using-the-watershed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to double-check each Mat has the type you think it does by using the `myMat.depth()` and `myMat.channels()` functions. The function `watershed` uses two Mat arguments. The first should be an 8-bit, 3-channel image, and the second should be a 32-bit single-channel image.

If they are not the right kind of image, use `cvtColor` to convert from what you have to what you need.

Comment: i'm really in need of help with this question, can you help me, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216402/how-to-improve-image-segmentation-using-the-watershed